# What do you call someone who accesses something?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, someone who accesses an IT system?

Edit: for clarity, I'm not assuming any intent or relationship.  For example, not a "hacker" or "vandal" or "client".  I'm looking for the most generic term.  I had considered "accessor", which seems natural, but I did not see that in my dictionary lookup.  I'm happy with that term, though, since it would be understandable to a reader even if not familiar.

Comment: What is the manner and purpose of the access?

Comment: In some contexts, “actor” or “agent” might work, but they might not be good in general — for example,  what do you call someone who accesses a chair or a movie theater?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a technical discussion about the act of performing the access itself, they're the *accessor*.

If it's a discussion about the system they're accessing, they might just be the *client* or *user*.